# Differential Equations Lectures or books from a theoretical perspective?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am looking for some differential equation lectures from a theoretical perspective, not a strictly computational one. I found the [MIT 18.03](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEC88901EBADDD980) lectures which (as the professor says towards the end of the first lectures) "is not going to be a course for those theoretically inclined." I would prefer something more geared towards the theory of differential equations. Book and other resource recommendation are also welcome, but I would prefer lectures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you're looking for lectures (unfortunately I also failed to find any) but as a compromise I have been really impressed with VI Arnold's *Ordinary Differential Equations.* It's very geometrical, and rigorous in the enlightening sense (rather than the paranoid-the-sky-will-fall-on-your-head sense.)

To give one very simple example - in the first chapter he gives a rigorous discussion of coordinate transforms. In most calculation-based courses, to transform to polar coordinates, you just algebraically replace $x$ by $ r\cos\theta $ and you blindly apply the chain rule to get

$$ \dot{x} =\dot{r}\cos \theta - r\dot{\theta }\sin \theta$$

and similarly for $\dot{y}.$ But Arnold instead discusses the geometric meaning of such a transform - as a transform of the underlying vector field, and shows that the substitution above should *really* be thought of as multiplying the local velocity field by the Jacobian (which approximates differentiable transformations arbitrarilly well in an arbitrarilly small region.)

Comment: +2, if that were possible. +1 for the great recommendation, which I will definitely look into, and +1 for "rigorous in ... the paranoid-the-sky-will-fall-on-your-head sense."